# Magento: Place Googly Analytics code just before </head>

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics

I am trying to place the Google Analytics code just before the closing head tag in Magento and it isn't working. I've been trying for hours now and it's driving me nuts!

I tried all tutorials which I've found on Google, but none of them do the job. For example this one: http://magebase.com/magento-themes/place-googleanalytics-before-head/

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/googleanalytics.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
        <reference name="before_head_end">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" after="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml (there is no page.xml in app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/) looks like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                ...
                <block type="core/text_list" name="before_head_end" as="before_head_end" after="-" />
            </block>
            ...
        </block>
    </default>
    ...
</layout>
```

I also moved getChildHtml() ?> to the bottom in app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/page/html/head.phtml.

Now, the code appears in the head tag, but there are still many inline JavaScript codes placed after the Analytics code. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to System -> Configuration

On the left hand side go to:
General -> Design -> HTML HEAD

About half way down there is a block called 'Miscellaneous Scripts'
If you paste your google analytics code there it will appear in the head.

This section is useful if you multi-store, and can keep all the analytics seperate :)

Comment: That does not work. The code is placed inside the head tag, but not just before the closing head tag, which is what I want.

Comment: hello you will add google analytics code at bottom in head.phtml